# Maximum records can be stored at Riak database

Tags: riak, riak-search

Can anyone give an example of maximum record limit in Riak database with specific hardware details? please help me in this case.I'm going to build a CDR information system. Will it be suitable to select Riak as my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riak uses the 2^160 SHA-1 hash value to identify the partitions to store data in. Data is then stored in the identified partitions based on the bucket and key name. The size of the hash space is therefore not related to the amount of data that can be stored. Two different objects that happen to hash to the same value will therefore not overwrite each other.

When working with Riak, it is important to model your data correctly and consider how it needs to be retrieved and queried during the design process. Ideally you should try to ensure that the vast majority of your queries can be done through direct key access. It is often recommended to de-normalise your data and use natural keys. For CDRs this may mean creating an object holding all CDRs for a subscriber per day. These objects can be named based on the subscriber id and date, making it easy to retrieve data directly by key. It is also often more efficient to retrieve a few larger objects than many small ones and perform filtering in the application rather than try to just get the exact data that is needed. I have described this approach in greater detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274070/how-to-append-data-to-a-riak-key-under-a-heavily-distributed-environment/15295260#15295260).

Answer (score -1):

The limit to the number of records (or key/value pairs) you can store in Riak is governed only by the size of the hash space: 2^160. According to WolframAlpha, this is the number:

1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976

In other words, go nuts. :)

Comment: Much like a (non-perfect) hash table, the hashing algo has no impact on the number of items that can be stored. The number of records you can store is governed by the backend you choose to use (bitcask, for example, the keys are in memory) and hardware (e.g. disk space, available ram, etc)

Comment: So if i needed to store 20000*3600*24*30*3 keys in my database what kind of RAM i needed when I using Bitcask back end? @Brian

Comment: How you store your data will depend on how you need to retrieve and query it. Inserting records one by one like you do in a relational database is most often not the optimal way to store data in Riak, unless the records e.g. are sessions and you know the key to look them up by. You may therefore end up storing fewer, larger objects. Having said that, there are calculators available for determining Bitcask memory usage at docs.basho.com.